# Strange behaviour of ProprityQueue

Tags: java, sorting, queue

I have configuration-elements put into a `PriorityQueue`. I am accessing the elements via

```
for (Element e : queue) {
  ...
}
```

This works well enough but after putting an additional configuration element into the queue, the ordering is disrupted. Even stranger, it depends on the sequence in which I enter the elements into the queue, whether sorting is correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

Javadoc of `PriorityQueue` states

> The Iterator is not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order.

basically, a `PriorityQueue` cannot be used in a `for-each` construct if ordering is required.

Depending on the code in question, either use iterated `queue.poll()` calls or switch to another datastructure like `List` and sort this exlipcitly via `Collections.sort()`.

As with the ordering being correct *sometimes*: You just got lucky at first.